# Extract from Union type where discriminator is also a Union

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, typescript-generics

I have a type like this:

```js
enum Type {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C'
}

type Union =
 | {
     type: Type.A | Type.B;
     key1: string
   }
 | {
     type: Type.C;
     key2: string
   }

type EnumToUnionMap = {
  [T in Type]: {
    [k in keyof Extract<Union, {type: T}>]: string
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that `typeof EnumToUnionMap[Type.A]` is `never` (in reality, it's a generic key signature like `[x: string]: string` but that's because `Extract<Union, {type: T}>` returns type `never` when `T` is `Type.A` or `Type.B`) while `typeof EnumToUnionMap[Type.C]` is

```js
{
  type: Type.C,
  key2: string
}
```

as expected.

This all makes sense because the `type` in `EnumToUnionMap[Type.A]` is `Type.A | Type.B` and `Type.A != (Type.A | Type.B)` so they don't match and we get `never`.

Essentially what I need to do something like this:

```js
type EnumToUnionMap = {
  [T in Type]: {
    [k in keyof Extract<Union, T in Union['type']>]: string
  }
}
```

**Why I need to do this:**

I receive a response from an alerts endpoint that has this shape:

```
{
 type: Type,
 key1: string,
 key2: string
}
```

Both alerts of `Type.A` and `Type.B` provide `key1` while those of `Type.C` provide `key2`.
I need to map the keys in the response to column names in a grid (where some alert types share a common set of keys but have different display names for the columns):

```
const columnMap: EnumToUnionMap = {
  [Type.A]: {
    key1: 'Column name'
    // Note that in actuality this object will contain
    // multiple keys (i.e. multiple columns) for a
    // given `Type` so creating a map
    // between `Type -> column name` is not possible.
  },
  [Type.B]: {
    key1: 'Different column name'
  },
  [Type.C]: {
    key2: 'Another column name'
  }
}
```

This way, I can do something like the following:

```
const toColumnText = (alert) => columnMap[alert.type]

...

if (alert.type === Type.A) {
  const key1ColumnName = toColumnText(alert).key1 // typed as string
  const key2ColumnName = toColumnText(alert).key2 // Typescript warns of undefined key
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to process the response and get it to a unified shape so you don't need to check it every second line?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Due to the nature of the application, "processing the request" is essentially what I'm doing right now. I cannot really unify the response without losing details about it that I need to know in order to render the grid correctly.

Comment: Could you provide more details on the `columnMap` variable? Can you change the shape of this variable? if the `columnMap` becomes a map from `Type` to the new column name it all becomes easier.

Comment: @GBF_Gabriel I'm assuming you mean a map where `columnMap[Type.A] === 'Column name'`? That's not possible because the object will contain multiple keys. I've updated the question to clarify as much.

Comment: @JustinTaddei Could you provide a playground for that code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, you can't really use [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) here, because the relationship between the members of the union `Union` and the candidate types `{type: T}` that you have is not simple assignability.  Instead, you want to find the member `U` of the union `Union` such that `T extends U["type"]`.  You'll probably have to forget about the utility types that TypeScript provides and instead perform the type manipulation yourself.

---

One possible definition for `EnumToUnionMap` is this:

```
type EnumToUnionMap = { [T in Type]: Union extends infer U ? U extends { type: any } ? (
    T extends U["type"] ? { [K in keyof U as Exclude<K, "type">]: U[K] } : never
) : never : never }
```

It might look a bit daunting; let's make sure it at least does what you want.  IntelliSense shows that it evaluates to:

```
/* type EnumToUnionMap = {
    A: { key1: string; };
    B: { key1: string; };
    C: { key2: string; };
} */
```

Looks good.

---

Now that we know it does what you want, how does it do it?  Let's break the definition into pieces and analyze each piece:

```
type EnumToUnionMap = { [T in Type]: Union extends infer U ? U extends { type: any } ? (
    T extends U["type"] ? { [K in keyof U as Exclude]: U[K] } : never
) : never : never }
```

As in your version, we are [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the enum values, `Type.A`, `Type.B`, and `Type.C`.  For each such enum value `T`, we need to split `Union` into its union members, and collect the one we care about.  Writing `Union extends infer U ? U extends { type: any } ? ...` uses [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to copy `Union` into a new type parameter `U`, which can then be used to create a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) where `U` represents individual union members of `Union`.  So from here on, whenever we see `U`, we are dealing with just pieces of `Union`, not the whole thing.

```
type EnumToUnionMap = { [T in Type]: Union extends infer U ? U extends { type: any } ? (
    T extends U["type"] ? { [K in keyof U as Exclude]: U[K] } : never
) : never : never }
```

To determine which union member `U` of the union `Union` to select, we evaluate the conditional type `T extends U["type"] ? ... : never`.  The check `T extends U["type"]` is true if and only if `U`'s `type` property is a supertype of `T`.  If `T` is `Type.A` and `U` is `{type: Type.A | Type.B, ...}`, then this is true.  But if `T` is `Type.A` and `U` is `{type: Type.C, ...}`, then this is false.  By returning `never` when the check is false, we are only going to process the "right" member of `Union`.

```
type EnumToUnionMap = { [T in Type]: Union extends infer U ? U extends { type: any } ? (
    T extends U["type"] ? { [K in keyof U as Exclude]: U[K] } : never
) : never : never }
```

So we've found the right union member `U`, but we don't want to just return it, because it still contains the undesirable `type` property.  We could return `Omit<U, "type">` using [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys), but this unfortunately results in verbose IntelliSense like `Omit<{type: Type.A | Type.B; key1: string}, "type">` instead of the desirable `{key1: string}`.  So here I'm writing my own `Omit` type using [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) (the documentation explains how this alternative to `Omit` works).

---

There you go; the `EnumToUnionMap` type walks through each member of `Type`, extracts the member of `Union` whose `type` property is a supertype of it, and omits the `type` property from that member.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2FA3gWAFBW1AglAXigHJdiAaTHKAIUJJoqpwGF7iXjMBfTTAF0TIAqiACWAexCFm2AD6pZ1KIKQAuWEIB0+BfCRaaAbiXUA1sDgBGDQGd+AJzEgA5kt5YcC9J+UqhGvrAWiwmvsoWcABMdo7ObuEeAkJQAKLgEDASopIgALIAhgj0KFAA2jBQzppIALoaOVJQwAAe-KAAJrZVIABmwA5QwlAA-EPNbZ3dparAGgUgcFDco1AAFEqVre0gXUNlAESzB7WrpWUA0j1QkRK94wXdqS0AxgA2YB3AADwX5FBHIQHAB89X2F1OKw0IGAADcBpgAJRQaFwgYoqAw+GDJIYTAAegAVP4kGkMllGvkiiUlLgND4-NhIjYoPYnK4wtRuJycDR6aYcMzYuyXDzsNylCx+eFzJYYqy4hz3GEVoT8XwMC8pPYoFqPhAqQgNOlIBTxFJCsUiAycBVtLgwTa-EKSCwJPrpCAChBgFwZTh8fioAA5CTtFQACwK-GuBRe-DABTeYkEkbE3QkACMAFbAeNQADuYjeb11Un4BWcAuwgagEDAb34YgQb2QkW6azEWmCdYbTZbyD1kBAtmRvQkgwK1agtZcYnh0gABkFF6yJLqHMBo-EoAU60Vp7XM8B+AXgKAoMuUgBaYFlj2Y73AVfpzFhqAICS2WxiTOtrTuJQ4R2gYNCOtOLrEAAImIvT9JuIAxkOBqPj6fpckB1AgcELDgf6TJyhopAgGGEboshnpPuhOAeNwQA)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I learned a lot.

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript has the natural ability to narrow types using `&` so I wanted to give a solution a shot that doesn't need too much trickery. Below is the full code to achieve your expected result. Note the typing of the `toColumnText` function as well, as that's also part of the solution.

```
enum Type {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C'
}

type Union =
 | {
     type: Type.A | Type.B;
     key1: string;
   }
 | {
     type: Type.C;
     key2: string
   }

type FindByType<TWhere, T extends Type> = TWhere extends { type: infer InferredT }
  ? (InferredT extends T ? (TWhere & { type: T }) : never)
  : never;

type EnumToUnionMap = {
  [T in Type]: {
    // Change `FindByType<Union, T>[k]` to `string` to force all extracted properties to be strings intead of their original type
    [k in Exclude<keyof FindByType<Union, T>, 'type'>]: FindByType<Union, T>[k];
  }
};

const columnMap: EnumToUnionMap = {
  [Type.A]: { key1: 'Column name' },
  [Type.B]: { key1: 'Different column name' },
  [Type.C]: { key2: 'Another column name' }
}

const toColumnText = <T extends Type>(alert: { type: T }): EnumToUnionMap[T] => columnMap[alert.type];

const alertObj: Union = { type: Type.A, key1: 'test' };
if (alertObj.type === Type.A) {
  const key1ColumnName = toColumnText(alertObj).key1 // typed as string
  const key2ColumnName = toColumnText(alertObj).key2 // Typescript warns of undefined key
}
```

Comment: I've mark the other answer as accepted because of the thorough explanation but this is the solution I've decided to go with because I find the implementation easier to understand for anyone else who may come across it in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Note that if `key1` had a type of something like `number` instead of `string`, then you'd need to change the implementation of `EnumToUnionMap` a bit... right now the subproperties will always be `string` no matter what `Union` contains

Comment: Thank you for the note @jcalz, I've updated the answer to account for differently typed properties.

Comment: @jcalz retyping the sub-properties to `string` is actually the intended behavior because the `columnMap` is used to map the keys to their respective column names. So even if `key1` is of type `number`, the resulting type of `key1` in `columnMap` would have to be `string`.

Comment: I could have made that more explicit in the question.

Comment: Oh well then it's *my* answer that does the wrong thing, so ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz Well, the question is about extracting a type from the union. The rest is specific to my use case and easily adaptable.